# cake php returns error 500 while trying to delete a record from a sql server

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cakephp

controller:

```
public function delete_saldo($id = null)
    {
     if($this->Auth->user('role') !== 'admin'){
         return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Reparti', 'action' => 'index']);
     }else {
         $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
         $saldiMagazzino = $this->SaldiMagazzino->find('all',['conditions' => ['ID_SALDO = ' => $id]]);
            if ($this->SaldiMagazzino->delete($saldiMagazzino)) {
                $message = 'Saved';
            } else {
                $message = 'Error';
            }
            $this->set([
                'message' => $message,
                '_serialize' => ['message']
            ]);
        }
    }
```

jquery:

```
 function deleteLotto(id_Saldo) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "/api/saldi_magazzino/deleteSaldo/"+id_Saldo+".json",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
        });

    }
```

router:

```
$routes->resources('SaldiMagazzino', [
        'map'=>[
            'deleteSaldo/:id'=>[
                'action' => 'delete_saldo',
                'method' => 'DELETE'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

when i try to execute this, an internal server error 500 appears. DB is a mysql server. this runs on cake php V 0.2.9

edit: added router. forgot it

edit: when i try to execute the function this is how the call fails:

```
    Request URL:http://localhost/api/saldi_magazzino/deleteSaldo/200.json
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Response Headers
view parsed
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 07 Jul 2017 12:03:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 121
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Request Headers
view parsed
DELETE /api/saldi_magazzino/deleteSaldo/200.json HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost/index.php/articoli/check_magazzino
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.404341568.1456939522; Webstorm-edbc5810=5f1b2a4a-2e60-4ec4-a544-13a4735b30dd; CAKEPHP=jlbdjed9d109qbdpfp1slh9ar3
```

Comment: the url that you gave is a json url? but for deleting you need some route for the function where delete is written

Comment: url: "/api/saldi_magazzino/deleteSaldo/"+id_Saldo+".json", change this line, and give the url of that fucntion not some url.json like url: "/api/saldi_magazzino/deleteSaldo/"?id=id_Saldo

Comment: the jquery call sucessfull calls the function. the problem is that the controller is not able do delete the record and returns 500

Comment: Please give us more informations about the 500 error,
you can do this by opening your browser console, go to Network tab, do your ajax call and show us what "response" tab give you.

Comment: done, i pasted the request output of the browser in the question

Comment: If there's anything helpful, then it would hide behind the "_view source_" button. Anyways, you better check the error logs, whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion). Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: edited as u suggest

Comment: That's not what I suggested. What I suggested was to check your error logs (`/logs/*.log`) for the actual error message and the corresponding stacktrace, and to check the _last line_ in the mentioned file for the version number (ok, it's actually the second last, but it's definitely not the one that says `@since`).